# A linear algebra problem arising from complex geometry.

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is:

> Let $A\in M^{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ with $A^2=-I$, and let $\tilde A\in M^{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ with $\tilde A= -\tilde A^T$. Then there exists $B\in M^{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ such that $\tilde A=(BA)^T-BA$ and $B^T=B$ if and only if $\tilde A  A=(\tilde A  A)^T$.

**My attempt**

If such $B$ exists, then we have
\begin{align}
\tilde A=(BA)^T-BA
&\implies \tilde A= A^TB-BA\\
&\implies A^T\tilde A A= A^TA^TBA-A^TBAA\\
&\implies A^T\tilde A A= -BA+A^TB = \tilde A\\
&\implies \tilde AA= -A^T\tilde A = (\tilde AA)^T.
\end{align}
Hence we get one direction. But I got stuck on the converse claim.
Any helps would be highly appreciated!

**Remark:** For such $A$ and $\tilde A$, one can easily show that $\tilde A  A=(\tilde A  A)^T$ is equivalent to that $(A-i I)^T \tilde A(A-iI)=0$. This observation might help.

Comment: I met this problem when I wanted to show that $N_J=0$ is equivalent to that $J$ is integrable, where being integrable is understood via differential forms. If anyone is interested in this, I can talk about it in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of convenience, I write $K$ for $\tilde{A}$.

If $KA=(KA)^T$, then $KA=S$ for some symmetric matrix $S$. Therefore $K=SA^{-1}=-SA$. As $K$ is skew-symmetric, we have $K$ is also equal to $-K^T=-(-SA)^T=A^TS$. Therefore
$$
K=\frac12(K+K)=\frac12(-SA+A^TS)=(BA)^T-BA
$$
where $B=\frac12S$.